# jqgrid php cannot populate the grid

Tags: php, jqgrid

I am trying using the jqgrid. I set the column, and i attached to that the widget. Everything is working except the grid does not contain data. It only contains an empty row. Column, widgets (like the calendar) works.

The following is the beginning of my grid setting:

```
// Create the jqGrid instance 
$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);

// Write the SQL Query 
 $grid->SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM `$table_name`";

 // set the ouput format to json 
 $grid->dataType = 'json';

 $grid->table = "$table_name";
  $grid->setPrimaryKeyId("matter_party_ID");
 $grid->serialKey = false;

$grid->setColModel();

// Set the url from where we obtain the data 
$grid->setUrl(????????);

$grid->addCol(array( etc. etc.
```

As you can see I am retriving the data with a a database query and returning a jason object to the grid:

```
// Write the SQL Query 
 $grid->SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM `$table_name`";

 // set the ouput format to json 
 $grid->dataType = 'json';
```

But the data is not there. After few invane searches I have been suggested to add the line:

```
$grid->setUrl(????????);
```

But I don't understand it. Why do I need to set a url if the data has been fetch on the current url using a select? Can you help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Watch the [link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid). As given here when you are not assigning arrays to the **jqGrid** you need to provide a `url` from where the data can be retrieved. This is because the **jqgrid** needs formatted data in the form of **json** or **xml** and doesn't process **resultset** directly. You could select the data and process it as required as shown in the [link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid) and then use the **php** as a `url` for your **jqgrid** which is defined in another **php** file.

Comment: dear Ajo, thank you for your help but unfortunately the example is using another version of the component and I need to make my version to work. But still appreciate the time you take to try to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question in case someone needs to solve the same or a similar problem. In the:

```
 $grid->setUrl(????????);
```

I pass a php file like grid.php that calls the function that builds the grid again!

```
$grid->setUrl('grid.php');
```

The problem is that when I generate a file through my own MVC it automatically adds a header and a footer compromising the json object returned by the grid constructor and not allowing the grid to be populated! I got rid of header and footer and the data magically reappeared!